# Github repository user group definition

Tags: git, repository, member, code-collaborator

I'm recently using github heavily and confused with the following terms:

1. Collaborators
2. Members
3. Assignee

Who could be assigned to an issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Assigning issues and pull requests to other GitHub users](https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/)"

> You can only create assignments for yourself, [collaborators on personal projects](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator), or [members of your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-teams) with read permissions on the repository.